# Number of Objects of Controller Class in Spring MVC web-app

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I have two questions:

Q1. Regarding the lifecycle of "servlet object" ? As we know that Request and Response Objects are created per access but Servlet Object is not created per access.Different requests have different threads, not instances so that it may consume less resources.So how does serveral reuest are served simultaneously ?I get that this wont be an issue when you are reading from DB but when it comes to writing it will create an issue ? How does big companies like amazon or any online booking services handle this [from servlet side] ?

Q2. How many objects of controller class is created when we make a spring mvc web-app[using by default configurations]; I believe the ans is 1 as component scan happens only once !!...but again it brings me back to previous question how does multiple request can work using single object without interfering ??...

A simple example might make my ques clear:
Suppose if I have this controller class like:

```
class controller{
void add(a,b){ blah blah...}
void sub(a,b){ blah blah...}
void multiply(a,b){blah blah...}
};
```

Now if there are 3 threads t1,t2 and t3 which want to access add,sub and multiply simultaneously using single object of controller!!..how will they do it simultaneously ??

Wouldnt Synchronization imply that threads have to wait for their turn. I mean to say untill the thread which has the object is done with it others thread will wait. So they wouldnt simultaneously work but wait. How big companies manage this simultaneous actions

Comment: Take a look at [Synchronization] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) and [Time Slice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Time_slice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A servlet, just like a Spring MVC controller, are singletons. A unique instance is thus used to serve multiple requests concurrently.

This should not a problem because a servlet or a Spring MVC controller are stateless objects: they take input, and produce output, without modifying any in-memory state. If they do, then access to this in-memory state must be properly synchronized.

Regarding the access to the database, that's typically handled by the database itself. Relational databases offer ACID guarantees, that allow accessing the database concurrently, using transactions. You could have deadlocks if you write two rows in the inverse order for example, but that deadlock would be detected by the database and one of the thread would get an exception, and its transaction would be rollbacked, leaving the database in a consistent state.

Other databases use more pessimistic locks, allowing access to only one thread at a time to their collections.

Comment: So what you are saying is that one object can be used by multiple threads to call execute different functions at same time. in example mentioned in question, is it possible that thread t1,t2,t3 can execute add,sub and multiply "concurrently" using single object of controller !!..

Comment: Yes, that's the whole principle of threads: they execute code (whatever it is), concurrently. The three threads might also all execute the same method of the same object concurrently.